# Set matrix zeros

Tags: c++11

"  I am trying to write algorithm which sets ith row jth coumn to zeros 
     in case of A[i][j]=0."

" I tried by printing the elements of matrix A While the third for loop
      is assigning zeros to the jth column of matrix as well as after the 
     completion of whole function.   Surprisingly in the first case allthe
      elements of first column are
     zero but in the second case last element of column is 1.""

```
 #include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

/*FUNCTION TO FIND ZEROS AND ASSIGN ith AND jth row AND columns zero

    */

     void setZeroes(vector<vector<int> > &A) {
     string a,b;/* string a is  created to store indexes of rows whose 
     elemnts are to be converted to zero if atleast one element in the       
      row is occupied by zero and similarly b is for columns*/


    /*for loop to find the indexes of zero elements*/


    for(int i=0;i<A.size();i++){

        for(int j=0;j<A[0].size();j++){

            if(A[i][j]==0){

     /*append function stores the indexes in strings*/

            a.append(to_string(i));b.append(to_string(j));}
        }
    }

     /*for loop to assign zeros to the elements of ith row*/

    for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++){

       int j=atoi(&a[i]),k=0;
       while(k<A[j].size()){
       A[j][k]=0;

           k++;}

    }

        /*for loop to assign zeros to the elements of jth column*/

      for(int i=0;i<b.length();i++){

       int j=atoi(&b[i]),k=0;
       while(k<A.size()){
       A[k][j]=0;  //every element in A is assigned zero at this point

           k++;
       }
       }
       }

     //driver function


   int main()
   {
  vector<vector<int>>A={{0,0},{1,1}};

 //invoking the setZeroes function
   setZeroes(A); for(int i=0;i<A.size();i++){

        for(int j=0;j<A[0].size();j++){

           cout<<A[i][j]<<" ";// (error)Here A[1][0] is printed as 1
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }


   return 0;
    }



 Input:[
 [0, 0]
 [1, 1]
         ]



    Expected:[
    [0, 0]
    [0, 0]
    ]
    Actual:
     [
      [0, 0]
      [1, 0]
             ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `atoi(&a[i])` and that `atoi(&b[i])` are wrong.

You suppose that `a` and `b` keep indices in range `<0,9>`. So to access them you can substract 48 (ascii code of 0 char):

```
int j = a[i] - 48; // the same with b[i]
```

or you can create one-character string, then use `atoi` to convert it into integer:

```
int j = atoi( string(1,a[i]).c_str() ); // this ctor takes one char and creates string
```

By doing `atoi(&a[i])` you are creating integer value starting at `i-item` to the end of string - it is not what you want.

---

If index can have two or more digits, you need to use some different container to store them, for example vector of string.

Answer (score -1):

```
**javascript**

let setZero = function(matrix) {
      let m = matrix.length;
      let n = (matrix[0] || []).length;
      for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
          if (matrix[i][j] === 0) {
            left(i, j, m, n, matrix);
            right(i, j, m, n, matrix);
            up(i, j, m, n, matrix);
            down(i, j, m, n, matrix);
          } else if (matrix[i][j] === '#') {
            matrix[i][j] = 0;
          }
        }
      }
    };
    
    let left = function (i, j, m, n, matrix) {
      for (var k = j - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
        matrix[i][k] = 0;
      }
    };
    
    let right = function (i, j, m, n, matrix) {
      for (var k = j + 1; k < n; k++) {
        matrix[i][k] = matrix[i][k] === 0 ? 0 : '#';
      }
    };
    
    let up = function (i, j, m, n, matrix) {
      for (var k = i - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
        matrix[k][j] = 0;
      }
    };
    
    let down = function (i, j, m, n, matrix) {
      for (var k = i + 1; k < m; k++) {
        matrix[k][j] = matrix[k][j] === 0 ? 0 : '#';
      }
    };
```